# How to get the current product version in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I programmatically get the current product version in C#?

My code:

```
VersionNumber = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

I am getting VersionNumber=1.0.0.0, but the current version is 1.0.0.12.

Comment: Check what is it returning in `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName()`

Comment: Also, are you looking for the assembly version or are you actually looking for the ClickOnce app version?

Comment: "the current version is 1.0.0.12" - set where? What do you see for the file version in explorer (tiles view, or properties, version)

Comment: Are you trying to read the "Assembly version" or the "Assembly file version"? - See <Your project>\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer.

Comment: No that can be done in two lines code thats what i did previously. I wanted the production version means deployed version not the Assembly file version.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I got the answer to my question its Just give the reference to System.Deployment.Application and though it wont work in developement of the visual studio but it will work once the application is deployed.

```
//using System.Deployment.Application;
//using System.Reflection;
public string CurrentVersion
{
    get
    {
        return ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
               ? ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString()
               : Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not the "product version." It's the "file version."

Answer (score 114):

There are three versions: assembly, file, and product. To get the product version:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fileVersionInfo.ProductVersion;
```

Comment: Quite ridiculous how two version settings that are snugly side by side in the project properties aren't even the same class internally. Heck, even the properties in the two classes aren't the same; the last part is referred to as "revision" in the assembly version, but as "private" in the file version.

Comment: This seems can not be used when I upgraded to .NET 6.0 with single file packing.

Answer (score 20):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version
```

Comment: GetEntryAssembly is the key point to get the running application even the code is in a DLL assembly

Comment: This isn't the production version.  The product version is a version represneted as a string, which is thus capable of storing the version info in SemVer format.

Answer (score 19):

Another approach to getting the product version (which is specified using the [`AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute.aspx)) is

```
private static string AssemblyProductVersion
{
    get
    {
        object[] attributes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute), false);
        return attributes.Length == 0 ?
            "" :
            ((AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute)attributes[0]).InformationalVersion;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better in circumstances where access to the file system is not available (e.g. SqlClr).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var thisApp = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName(thisApp.FullName);
VersionNumber = "v. " + name.Version;
```

Also, see [this Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.version) on the `AssemblyName.Version` property.

Comment: IS that the assemblyversion or the assemblyFileVersion?

Comment: the code that you replied with. Actually the thing is i need the current version of the application that we are building. So how can i get that. The same that we have in the solution properties.

Comment: I am using MVVM pattern and its giving me view models version number.

Comment: That is not the ProductVersion but the FileVersion, they are not the same.

Comment: FTR, AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion  can be found on AssemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 6):

In C# you need to use reflection and diagnostics

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fileVersionInfo.ProductVersion;
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have network deployed version or using other project as start up project.

Answer (score 4):

All these answers ask for the assembly with `.GetExecutingAssembly()`.
If you have this code in a dll, it will return the dll version number.

Swap that call for `GetCallingAssembly()` to get the place in your code that wanted to know.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns version like 2.1.15
/// </summary>
public static String ProductVersion
{
    get
    {
        return new Version(FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location).ProductVersion).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var productVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(SomeClassFromDesiredAssembly).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion;
```

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation so others can understand your code and how it fixes the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as most of you. It would always show 1.0.0.0 unless you manually went in and updated assemblyInfo.cs to the version you wanted to display. I think we wanted to display the publish version-revision number under the project properties but that doesn't seem to be an option (from what I've read).

I'm not sure if back when these comments were made this existed, but now in the **assemblyinfo.cs** there is a way to do this automatically. I too was not content with having to manually update these with every publish.

`// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]`

That * auto-increments with each publish. It won't be the same as the publish number you see under the project properties, but it definitely increments and is definitely better than doing it by hand.

You then have a couple options to display it as mentioned above. I personally used this which I found on another site

`Version version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
lblRevision.Text = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision);`

Comment: Doing this means you only need to update assemblyInfo.cs when you change a major or minor version as build and revision are handled for you. Changing the publish version has no affect on this.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach without dealing with assembly location:

```cs
Assembly someAssembly = ...;
var productVersion = someAssembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()?.InformationalVersion;
```