# Is it possible to bind a TextBlock's Text to an applications AssemblyVersion?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, version-numbering

If I have a TextBlock in the corner of my UserControl is it possible to bind the Text property to my Assembly Version Number Which is in AssemblyInfo.cs

**WPF:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AssemblyVersion}"/>
```

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a readonly property named `AssemblyVersion` and bind it.

```
public Version AssemblyVersion
{
    get
    {
        return Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Is there much difference between the way to get the Version in this method and the one used [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493715/how-to-get-current-product-version-in-c)? apart from your way being much simpler

Comment: @user1 Yes, [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6499302/2530848) adds support for application deployed via clickonce. Otherwise, my answer is fine

Answer (score 4):

here is a pure XAML approach

```
<TextBlock xmlns:ref="clr-namespace:System.Reflection;assembly=mscorlib">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="Version">
            <Binding.Source>
                <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetName">
                    <ObjectDataProvider.ObjectInstance>
                        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetExecutingAssembly"
                                            ObjectType="{x:Type ref:Assembly}" />
                    </ObjectDataProvider.ObjectInstance>
                </ObjectDataProvider>
            </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

in this example we are leveraging the `ObjectDataProvider` to retrieve the desired (executing or can say current) assembly followed by it's version.

ObjectDataProvider is quite useful for retrieving results from method calls.

Answer (score 0):

To get the assembly version you can use this in code behind:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

    #region - Version -
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the FileVersion
    /// </summary>
    public static string Version => FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FileVersion;
    #endregion - Version -
```

and in the Xaml code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Version}"/>
```

that's all