# Detect the C# version at compile time

Tags: c#

Is it possible to detect if the current version of C# is 6 or above with a preprocessor directive, so at compile time?

I want to do something like this:

```
var myVar = ...;
string name;

#if VERSION_6_OR_MORE
    name = nameof(myVar);
#else
    name = "myVar";
#endif
```

I use Visual Studio 2015 and C# 6, so I can use `nameof()`. Someone else wanting to compile this code however may be using an older version, where `nameof()` isn't present.

I want to use a preprocessor directive so I can keep the `nameof()` in C# 6, but someone else who doesn't use that version can compile it as well.

Comment: Why do you want to do such thing?

Comment: Check out this answer: [How to get current Product Version in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7382420/6741868).

Comment: @KeyurPATEL The OP needs the .NET Framework version - not the build version of his component.

Comment: @Filburt I see, then would this help? [Is there an easy way to check the .NET Framework version?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/951915/6741868)

Comment: Sounds like a typical [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/143302) - use a dictionary instead of messing with reflection.

Comment: I edited the question, I want pre processor instruction. I want to use `nameof` if I have C#6, else I want to use other way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect target framework version at compile time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526/detect-target-framework-version-at-compile-time)

Comment: @Kris no, it's not a duplicate. Framework Version is not related to C# version. You can target .NET 2.0 with C# 6 and vice versa.

Comment: imagine tracking down a bug that you colleague finds and you cannot reproduce when you have 50 of such blocks

Comment: @CodeCaster it was more about the creation of a "custom" constant than the meaning of that constant but I guess you have a point there.

Comment: @Kris agreed, that is _a_ solution, but then the question is: what information do you feed this constant with? Which isn't addressed in the duplicate, as that one is about .NET version and not C# version. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster, i retracted my duplicate vote and already adressed that in my answer

Comment: Thanks you all for your comments, I will keep CodeCaster's solution, give up `nameof`. It's maybe possible to detect the version but in my case the maintenance will be hell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `nameof()` operator is meant to reduce maintenance: using it you don't have identifiers hidden in strings, so when you rename a variable, parameter or member, the place where you use it (for example an `ArgumentNullException(nameof(paramName))`) will be updated when you refactor the `paramName` name.

Now using your approach, you're effectively **doubling** your maintenance surface instead of reducing it (as you now have both the string variant *and* the `nameof()` version, both of which having to be maintained), negating the use of `nameof()` altogether.

So if you want to support older C# versions, stick to features that work in those versions: use identifiers in strings instead.

Comment: You must be right, I prefer use `nameof`, it allows to rename variable without have to check all the strings depending on this variable. But if my colleagues can't update it will be hard to maintain. I will give up `nameof` then :-(

Answer (score 7):

You can explicitly specify language version and define conditional constant in your project file:

```
<LangVersion>6</LangVersion>
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
<DefineConstants Condition="'$(LangVersion)' == '6'">DEBUG;TRACE;LANG_VERSION_6</DefineConstants>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a pre-existing directive. But, here's what you can do:

1. Define two build configurations: Say CSharp6 and CSharp5 (in the configuration
   manager).
2. Select C6 from the configuration manger, and then go to the project properties. And define a symbol say CSHARP6.
3. Change configurations and go to CSharp5
4. Open project properties again and define a new symbol: CSHARP5

Then your directive conditional would look like:

```
#if CSHARP6
    name = nameof(myVar);
#else
    name = "myVar";
#endif
```

Delegate the selection of the configuration profile to the building agent, or as part of an instruction manual for compilation of the project.

Answer (score 1):

The C# compiler doesn't let you define *symbols* with a numerical value. Any symbol is either *defined* or *undefined*, which means it's just a boolean.

Neither [`#define`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx)/[`/define`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx) nor [`#if`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) support any syntax other than boolean.

All C# versions so far are backwards-compatible with previous versions (except for some nuances like iterator variable semantics in `foreach` loops), so if you want to write code compatible with older versions, just don't use the newer features.

You could, define a symbol externally after detecting the available compiler version in your build script, but it's not worth the hassle IMO, as the lower-version C# code will be more legible and maintainable than duplicate blocks scattered around your code.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about constants like that, but...

Something like `typeof(int).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion` could help out at runtime.

Additionally: 
You can create constants:

```
<DefineConstants Condition=" '$(LanguageVersion)' == 'v6.0' ">USING_CS6</DefineConstants>
<DefineConstants Condition=" '$(LanguageVersion)' != 'v6.0' ">NOT_USING_CS6</DefineConstants>
```

- @see [Detect target framework version at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526/detect-target-framework-version-at-compile-time)
- @see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj80.csharpprojectconfigurationproperties3.languageversion.aspx

I have not tested this though.

Comment: I don't think so, op wants to find this on runtime.

Comment: @Fka, it's compile time.

Comment: @Fka, Wai means your sentence in the first comment does not mean what you think it means. In fact it means the opposite of what you intended.