# Detecting C# Version Number at Compile Time - Feature Checking

Tags: c#, compilation, preprocessor-directive

I'm installing **Visual Studio 2017** to play around with some of the new features, in my case the new language features for  **tuples**.

#### **Use Case**

My colleagues are using VS2015, while I test out VS2017. I want to take some existing libraries where we return objects of `Tuple<?,?>` and rewrite a couple of them to test it out etc. Obviously I will be committing code (even though it is in test) back to our git **dev** branches (TFS).

#### **Question**

Is there a compiler directive that I can use to detect the version of C# currently in operation? example like `#CSHARP_VERSION_7` that I can wrap around my rewritten methods, so when my colleagues merge back in (dev) my new C# 7.0 tuple methods wont cause compilation issues?

FYI, I have read the following:

[Detect the C# version at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974078/detect-the-c-sharp-version-at-compile-time)

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx

Comment: Whats wrong with the solutions outlined in your references ? Just define the constant in VS.net Debug settings and your problem is solved.

Comment: I'd say your best bet is to decide together with your colleagues on which C# version to use. You can use an older C# version on VS2017 I reckon.

Comment: Isnt it something like CSHARP7 ?

Comment: @PhillipH: Thanks for taking the time to comment - I was thinking of defining my own, just wanted to check there weren't any MS ones before (dry and all that ;) )

Comment: Just curious, any reason your doing this in a dev branch and not just creating a new one off of them for testing purposes?  You could find that you don't want the changes and need to remove them anyway.