# How to find daemon application version using .Net Core 3.1 with systemd?

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, systemd

I have a C# .NET Core 3.1 daemon application which is running in RedHat Linux. Application output type is console application

How to find version of the application when i run the following command
**testApp.service -v**

Could you please help me on this?

Example:
if we run **rsyslog -v** command, the rsyslog version details will be shown in terminal window.
Same way, my application version details has to shown in terminal window.

Regards,
Prabs

Comment: I think you should write sth. to parse the ```args[]```, if there is a ```v``` argument set simply output the version. The version itself depends on how you define version: Fileversion, application version (hardcoded), build version, etc. Maybe this can help you [Product Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493715/how-to-get-the-current-product-version-in-c)

Comment: What do you mean by sth? I have written C#.Net core daemon code

Comment: sth = something :) ...